# AUTOENCODER - Reshape Data to have deeper architecture?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, autoencoder

I have a data frame of 7 variables (columns) which I consider too less to have a proper data compression in my case .
What do you think about reshaping the data ? for example

```
[1000 , 7] => [100,70]  ## 7 columns to 70 columns
```

Does it sound good ? I have some doubt about that ,as It will affect the data comprehension of my neural network.
Thank you

Comment: That doesn't make sense

Comment: Yes I know that ,maybe could I convert my data into segments like it is done with LSTM models ,segmented using a windows size ? and make an auto-encoder based architecture ? The question is ,should I use only  LSTM (or RNN ,whatever) layers ,or maybe  can I do it using only Dense layer ?